# sqldf - Alter syntax to add new column to data frame

Tags: r, sqldf

I want to add a new field to a data frame by `sqldf`.

```
> data(mtcars)
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf("alter table mtcars add newfield  int not null")
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL
> 
> sqldf("alter table mtcars add newfield  int")
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
Warning message:
In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
  Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries
```

I get an empty data frame from the last command. The sql expression seems ok. But I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan, This works, Thank you. But I don't know why another `select` is needed?

Comment: Another `select` is to make sure about the data (whether a new column is created or not) and display it to the output console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add new column using `sqldf` (I am not sure about adding not `null` column):

```
data(mtcars)
library(sqldf)
sqldf(c("alter table mtcars add newfield numeric","select * from mtcars"))
```

Sample Output:

```
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb newfield
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       NA
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4       NA
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       NA
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1       NA
```

Comment: If I want to add two fields at once `sqldf(c("ALTER TABLE mtcars ADD afield numeric, add bfield numeric", " select * from mtcars"))`. It goes wrong.

Comment: You can try this way (this is not smart way): `sqldf(c(("alter table mtcars add newfield numeric"),c("alter table mtcars add newfield1","select * from mtcars")))
`